# how to concatenate html strings using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to perform the below operation with jQuery without using '+' sign?

```
var appendToResult = "<h4>Whoops, we noticed something.</h4><ul>";

    appendToResult = appendToResult+"<li><p>Please enter your Current Password.</p></li><li><p>Please enter a New Password.</p></li>";
```

Comment: Why.............

Comment: `appendToResult+='my text';` ?

Comment: concat() in javascript, by +1 @AndrewWhitaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or...

```
var appendToResult = "<h4>Whoops, we noticed something.</h4><ul>";
appendToResult = appendToResult.concat("<li><p>Please enter your Current Password.</p></li><li><p>Please enter a New Password.</p></li>");
```

What exactly is the source of your displeasure with the gentle plus sign, which never did anyone harm?

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking for a way to concatenate strings without using a plus sign, here's a way, no jQuery required:

```
var arr = ['text thing 1', 'other text', 'more text', 'etc'];
var str = arr.join(' ');
```

If you have a jQuery object you're trying to append text to, you can do that like this:

```
var myObj = $('.myclass');
myObj.append('my appended text here');
```